# NAS Storage not auto-mounting on-load

Tags: 12.04, startup, automount, fstab

I'm using a [GoFlex Home Storage device from Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/home-entertainment/media-sharing-devices/goflex-home/). 
Now that I've figured out [how to auto-mount my NAS storage  by editing `fstab`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163201/example-of-procedure-for-nas-storage-auto-mounting). I'm having another issue.

`sudo mount -a` on a started system mounts the drives as I would expect.

However, at startup, the auto-mounting procedure fails. A review of `dmesg` suggests that the process fails because the network is not available.

Is there a way to create and run a shell script at startup that would run the mount command as root? (After startup, `sudo mount -a` works like a charm)

Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163201/example-of-procedure-for-nas-storage-auto-mounting

Comment: @Mitch  That was his earlier question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for 12.10**

`sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Now you can use `cifs` in `/etc/fstab` instead of `smbfs`

**Solution for 12.04**

`sudo apt-get install smbfs`

Change `cifs` to `smbfs` in fstab listings.

Although it was primarily trial and error. This Ubuntu wiki page was highly useful and contains information about other common setups:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Can you edit your question to mention the kind of NAS it is? sbmfs is old and not supposed to be used but if it's what works on a certain model then we should probably document it. thanks!